# How can I improve the performance of this select into query

Tags: sql-server

I would appreciate if someone advises on how to improve the performance of a stored procedure with the following query (the functions are very small and I don’t believe they are penalising the performance):

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.[description], ' Org',''), ' group',''),'Organization full name','Org') 
                                                                                                AS OrgColumn1, 

                REPLACE(REPLACE(c.[description], ' Org',''), ' group','') + ' Organization'     AS OrgColumn2, 

                CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.fn_OrgGrantPageAccess(c.id,@contactId) = 1 
                    AND (c.id <> 13 AND c.id <> 31) 
                        THEN '<a href="OrgMainPage.aspx?id='+CAST((c.id) as varchar(15))+'">'+
                        replace(replace(c.[description], ' Org',''), ' group','') + ' Org</a>' 

                    WHEN dbo.fn_OrgGrantPageAccess(c.id,@contactId) = 1 
                    AND (c.id = 13 OR c.id = 31) 
                        THEN '<a href="OrgMainPage.aspx?id='+CAST((c.id) as varchar(15))+'">'+
                        c.[description]+'</a>'
                    ELSE 
                    replace(replace(c.[description], ' Org',''), ' group','') + ' Org' 
                END                                                                             AS OrgColumn3, 

                c.id                                                                            AS OrgColumn4,
                dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn5(c.id)                                                      AS OrgColumn5,
                dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn6(c.id)                                                      AS OrgColumn6,
                dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn7(c.id)                                                      AS OrgColumn7,
                dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn8(c.id)                                                      AS OrgColumn8,
                dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn9(c.id)                                                      AS OrgColumn9,
                dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn10(c.id)                                                     AS OrgColumn10

INTO            #T

FROM            table_c                 c

INNER JOIN      table_s                 s 
ON              c.id                    =s.id

INNER JOIN      table_t                 t 
ON              s.type_id               = t.type_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN table_m                 m 
ON              c.id                    = m.OrgID

LEFT OUTER JOIN table_cal               cal 
ON              m.meetingid             = cal.calid

WHERE           t.type_id               = 3
AND             active                  = 1
AND             (c.org_1                = 1 
OR              c.org_1                 = 3)

ORDER BY        OrgColumn1
```

Comment: Hi, the first thing you should do it run it through the "Database Engine Tuning Advisor".  This will tell you what indexes and stats that it recommends.  You could see quite an improvement

Comment: Scalar functions with data access could kill the performance. It's easy to check -- remove the function calls from the select and check the execution time.

Comment: It is not possible to lust look at a SQL text and tell why it's slow. Performance depends on many more things like schema and data. Insufficient information to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to rewrite `dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn` function from scalar-valued to table-valued and then `cross apply` it to main result set.
If you can provide source code for `dbo.fn_OrgGetColumn` function I can help you with rewriting it to table-valued.

There you can find good explanation with examples: [Boost Your T-SQL with the APPLY](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=6797&m=6796&ct=25528)

Comment: Thank you for your answers (Andrey and Dean)! I've been replacing scalar-valued functions with either "SELECT TOP 1" or "SELECT max()" and I can see big improvement. Thanks again.